# Virtual Machine Extension in Terraform, error due to Version

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

Below is the script. trying on windows machine.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "VMextn1" {
    name                 = "avmextn1"
    virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
    publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version = "1.10"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
    settings             = <<SETTINGS
      {
          "fileUris": ["https://storageforiotscripts.blob.core.windows.net/nodejsscript/installNodeJS.ps1"],
          "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file installNodeJS.ps1"      
      }
  SETTINGS
}
```

Tried changing versions to 1.1,1.5,1.9,2.0... and also auto_upgrade_minor_version to false.
Its throwing the following error in the image attached [Cannot update handler version or autoUpgradeMinorVerison and a conflict of other extensions with  typeHandler version 1.9 and autoUpgradeMinorVerison = false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Wdr.png) :

[image]

Comment: Please don't post error as a screenshot, rather as text.

Comment: Important post that explains why it's important to include formatted text and not images of text: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

***According to my research it is not an version error, It is an extension and resource name error.***

> ErrorMessage: Cannot update handlerVersion or autoUpgradeMinorVersion for VM extension 'CustomScriptExtension'.  Change is in conflict with other extensions under handler 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension', with typeHandler version '1.9' and autoUpgradeMinorVersion 'False'.

- The above error indicates ***Custom Script Extension*** has already been installed as a resource name on the virtual machine.
- You might be giving CustomScriptExtension a different resource name than ***Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension***

-Ensure that the resource name is correct. The resource name can be anything. But, if the Custom Script Extension has already been set up, you can use the same extension for further steps of execution or else you can remove the previous extension if you using ***new or different*** extension.

***Reference:***

[Debug PowerShell scripts run by Custom Script Extension or Run Command - Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/debug-customscriptextension-runcommand-scripts)

Comment: thank you. you were right. i could resolve my issue with your help